# @Html Partial error, using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

Error:

> CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method
>   named 'Partial' but appears to have an extension method by that name.
>   Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting
>   the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the
>   extension method syntax.

Not sure how to sort this issue.
Model:

```
namespace MVCRecsStarter.ViewModels{ public class AdminViewModel
{
    public Category category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Rec> recs { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> categoriesrecs { get; set; }
}}
```

**View:**

```
<div id='leftItemTemplate'>
    @Html.Partial("admin", Model.category)
</div>

<div id='rightItemTemplate'>
    <h3>Find Rec to Update</h3>
    @Html.Partial("_select_recs", Model.recs)
    @if (Model.categoriesrecs != null)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_select_categories", Model.categoriesrecs)
    }
</div>
```

**_select_category:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Rec</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RecTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RecTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RecURL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RecURL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecURL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RecDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RecDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Image, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Category, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Create" />
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>}
```

**_select_rec:**

```
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("SelectRec", "Categories", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <p>
            <select name="recs">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <option value="@item.rec">@item.rec</option>
                }
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="action"
                   value="Select Rec" />
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Admin()
    {
        Category category = new Category();
        IEnumerable<Rec> recs = repository.GetAllRecs();

        AdminViewModel adminViewModel = new AdminViewModel();
        adminViewModel.category = category;
        adminViewModel.recs = recs;

        return View(adminViewModel);
    }
```

**Model.Rec**

```
namespace MVCRecsStarter.Models{
public class Rec
{
  [Key, Display(Name = "ID")]
  [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
  public int RecId { get; set; }
  [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Title")]
  public string RecTitle { get; set; }
  Required, StringLength(150), Display(Name = "Link")]
  public string RecURL { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000), Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string RecDescription { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150), Display(Name = "Image")]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(15)]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You sure this is valid? Seems to be a list (collection), not a member? (Rec)Model.recs

Comment: Try @Html.Partial("_select_recs", (IEnumerable<Rec>))Model.recs) and same for the other one that's a collection

Comment: No luck came up with the error: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Rec' could not be found

Comment: The error "Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched" tends to be caused when it can't figure out the type of the model or the model is purposefully dynamic, so if it can't find the namespace, that might be the issue.

Comment: Do you have a @model statement in the view? I don't see it here but figured you might have omitted it for brevity

Comment: Yes the model is @model MVCRecsStarter.Models.Rec

Comment: On the main view that's calling the partials? That doesn't seem like the right model. Didn't you want AdminViewModel? The error is coming from the main view, as its not even loading a partial.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question about which model that view is for? I'm getting a little confused because it seems to want to bind to an admin model, based on your fields, but then it calls a view that binds to admin model.

Comment: The model is used in therec view to display the details of the rec, but i need it to display the details on the admin page when an item is selected from a drop down box, which is also on the admin page. (Left Template and right Template) is the code for that. The problem im having is getting the drop down box with a list of rec's to display so i can select one and pull in the information such as the rec title and description so it can be edited. Sorry if im not clear on this, i'm a novice to this.

Comment: Hmmm, I still feel as though something is missing here. Here is what I would expect but do not see in your question: 1. the main view, the one with the left and right side, must be bound with @ model AdminViewModel  2. The partial view that you call like @Html.Partial("admin", Model.category) must be returned by a controller action named Admin that returns PartialviewResult. You should not re-use the method that returns ViewResult to return PartialViewResult (code smell and outside the scope of this discussion)  3. Partial views should be bound with respective @ model statements

Comment: I posted a working example given some of your code. I focused on it compiling and working to bind to one field of the model for each part. You should be able to take that and pop in your form code to go from there. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is working for me, if I understand what you're after. Note that there is a separate page for binding to the Category.

[image]
[image]

**AdminController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Admin
        public ActionResult Admin()
        {
            Category category = new Category() { Name = "TestC" };
            List<Rec> rc = new List<Rec>()
            {
                new Rec() { RecId=1, RecTitle="Test" }
            };

            AdminViewModel adminViewModel = new AdminViewModel();
            adminViewModel.category = category;
            adminViewModel.recs = (IEnumerable<Rec>)rc;

            return View(adminViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

**Admin.cshtml**

```
@model  WebApplication2.Models.AdminViewModel
    <div style="height:50px"></div>
<div id='leftItemTemplate' style="float:left;width:30%;border:1px solid black;">
    <p>Category div</p>
    @Html.Partial("adminCategory", Model.category)
</div>

<div id='rightItemTemplate' style="float:right;width:70%;border:1px solid black;">
    <p>Rec div</p>
    <h3>Find Rec to Update</h3>
    @Html.Partial("_select_recs", Model.recs)
    @if (Model.categoriesrecs != null)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_select_categories", Model.categoriesrecs)
    }
</div>
```

**_select_recs**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.Rec>

<h2>_select_recs</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>@item.RecTitle</li>
    }
</ul>
```

**AdminCategory** view

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Category
<h3>Category details here</h3>
<p><b>@Model.Name</b></p>
```

Comment: Ill continue this tomorrow and get back to you, thank you for your help.